# What happens if a SP2013 remote event receiver fails to connect to the target service?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

I have a Remote Event Receiver configured to notify a Web Service whenever a new list item is added (`ItemAdded`). This is working properly.

That said, it's imperative that each time a new list item is added it triggers a corresponding event on the remote server. In the event that my remote server goes down, and SharePoint 2013 sends a one-way (fire and forget) event anyway, is there any way of telling (via SharePoint or otherwise) that the newly added listitem did not successfully trigger the remote event?

Comment: Have you come any further in solving this?

Comment: No, unfortunately. It looks like we will actually be exploring an alternative so I'm not certain I need the solution anymore. I'm very disappointed with SharePoint 2013 (online especially) and the way remote event receivers are implemented. They seem very error prone and lack even basic debugging options.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to know that your event receiver was not triggered, then you can create 
workflow, that will request your "special" service (url) to ask it about latest triggered information.Yes, it may sounds stupid :) but it should work.
But I think that you should find reason, why your trigger was not fired.
I wrote two full step-by-step articles (with information about service bus configuration) about Remote Event Recevers in SharePoint Online:

1) Creating and Debugging of Remote Event Receivers for SharePoint Online 
http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2014/12/creating-and-debugging-of-remote-event.html

2) Adding Remote Event Receivers to list on Host web + Debugging
http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2015/01/adding-remote-event-receivers-to-list.html